# Imprimir vetor desconsiderando os valores repetidos

Tags: c++, array

> Fazer um algoritmo que leia um vetor de 50 elementos e imprima o vetor
>   desconsiderando os valores repetidos.

O código está dando a saída correta, mas se eu digito um número repetido, o programa solicita um novo até que eu digite um que ainda não exista no vetor. Como consertar isso?

```
int main(){
int vet[5], i, j, num;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     cout << ("Numero: ");
     cin >> vet[i];
     num = vet[i];
     for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if (vet[j] == num){
            --i;
            }
        }
     }

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << vet[i] << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Vou considerar que o enunciado é exatamente este. Já começa que você não está fazendo o que o enunciado pede. Note que ele tem duas partes: 1) "leia um vetor de 50 elementos" (você está muito mais que isso no *loop* que deveria ser bem simples; 2) "imprima o vetor desconsiderando os valores repetidos" (você está imprimindo tudo). Pode parecer bobagem, mas faz diferença. Programação é assim, tem que ficar atento a todos os detalhes. Aí neste segundo *loop* é que deve verificar se aquele valor já existe. Então provavelmente se você fizer isto, já saberá consertar o problema da saída do *loop*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou considerar que o enunciado é exatamente este. Você não está fazendo o que o enunciado pede. Note que ele tem duas partes:

1. "leia um vetor de 50 elementos" (você está fazendo muito mais que isso no *loop* que deveria ser bem simples;
2. "imprima o vetor desconsiderando os valores repetidos" (você está imprimindo tudo).

Pode parecer bobagem, mas faz diferença. Programação é assim, tem que ficar atento a todos os detalhes. Aí neste segundo *loop* é que deve verificar se um valor já existe.

Resolvendo isto, automaticamente não terá o problema do *loop* ficar empacado.

Sem modificar muito e sem otimizar da melhor forma possível (mas otimizei da forma mais óbvia) fiz um teste rápido que resolve da maneira como foi proposto. Não cheguei fazer nenhum teste extensivo. Também não modifiquei muito seu código ou melhorei a formatação da saída, acho que isto você sabe se virar.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_ITENS 50 //número de itens a serem lidos se quiser modificar para testes

int main() {
    int vet[MAX_ITENS];
    bool repetido;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ITENS; i++) {
         cout << ("Numero: ");
         cin >> vet[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ITENS; i++) {
        repetido = false;
         for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) { //verifica se existem iguais apenas entre os anteriores
             if (vet[j] == vet[i]) {
                repetido = true;
                break; //tem repetido, não precisa continuar com a procura
             }
         }
         if (!repetido) {
             cout << vet[i] << endl;
         }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ph1YIZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/etgfhkbu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/Unique.cpp).

Comment: Bigown, deste jeito o repetido não deveria dar sempre true não? Olha porque, você compara o vet[i] com o vet[j], inicialmente ambos têm o mesmo índice. Ou seja, olhando rápido, parece que você compara o mesmo vetor...

Comment: Não. Em nenhum momento `i`e `j` possuem o mesmo número. Esse teste foi feito.

Comment: Show de bola, @bigown.
Parece ser besta, mas tem coisas simples que pegam a gente.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: É normal quando está aprendendo.