# Apagar valores repetidos

Tags: lua, lua-table

Como eu poderia fazer para apagar valores repetidos em uma tabela?
Ex:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,3,2,1}
```

Como faria para apagar 3, 2 e 1, mantendo apenas um de cada?

Minha tabela é uma dentro de outra:

```
a = {
{a=1, b=2},
{a=2, b=3},
{a=1, b=2},
}
```

Nesse caso, o ultimo valor seria apagado, já que o `a` e o `b` dele e do primeiro são iguais. Os pares devem ser considerados como um valor só para efeito de comparação. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma abordagem mais tradicional para verificar a duplicidade conforme eu já havia feito em [outra resposta sobre C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37014/101).

```
a = {{a=1, b=2}, {a=2, b=3}, {a=1, b=2}, {a=3, b=2}, {a=1, b=2}}
 
for i = #a, 2, -1 do
    for j = i - 1, 1, -1 do
        if (a[j].a == a[i].a and a[j].b == a[i].b) then
            table.remove(a, i)
            break
        end
    end
end
 
-- demonstração do resultado:
for i, j in pairs(a) do
    print(i .. ". a=" .. j.a .. ", b=" .. j.b)
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bIm0nw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uhbzbdnu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/TableHandling.lua).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar outras tabelas e usar como variáveis "de sinal" (flags) para ver se o elemento já esta ou não no array. Se sua tabela tiver tabelas dentro, basta iterar por cada tabela dentro da primeira tabela:

```
local flags = {}
local a_filtrado = {}

for _, f in pairs(a) do
   for _,v in pairs(f) do
      if (not flags[v]) then
         a_filtrado[#a_filtrado+1] = v
         flags[v] = true
      end
   end
```

end

A tabela `a_filtrado` vai ter os elementos uma unica vez.

Comment: Teria como por um exemplo funcional no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com)? Não consegui fazer rodar seu código como está.